# ArgumentError: cannot interpret as DNS name: nil capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

Hi all can anyone help me to resolve the issue

'ArgumentError: cannot interpret as DNS name: nil'

The error is coming when doing capybara selenium integration testing in rails 4
here I am using jruby-1.7.9 and ruby version inside JRuby is 2.0.0p195
already I had used the Ruby version is 1.9.7 at that time I faced the error
'cant connect to chrome driver error'
in pure ruby like without using JRuby its the integration testing is working. but my application is in JRuby. and I am using ubuntu platform.
So anyone have any solution on this. what should I do to resolve this??

Here iam adding the exception backtrace

["/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/resolv.rb:1181:in `create'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/resolv.rb:1027:in`generate_candidates'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/resolv.rb:1052:in `resolv'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/resolv.rb:518:in`each_resource'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/resolv.rb:411:in `each_address'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/resolv.rb:120:in`each_address'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/resolv.rb:119:in`each_address'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/resolv.rb:97:in `getaddress'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/resolv.rb:48:in`getaddress'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv-replace.rb:10:in `getaddress'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/resolv-replace.rb:22:in`initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1178:in `open'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/net/http.rb:882:in`connect'", "org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:144:in `timeout'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/net/http.rb:881:in`connect'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/net/http.rb:866:in `do_start'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/net/http.rb:855:in`start'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/2.0/net/http.rb:582:in `start'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/capybara-2.9.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:81:in`responsive?'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/capybara-2.9.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:97:in `boot'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/capybara-2.9.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:72:in`initialize'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/capybara-2.9.1/lib/capybara.rb:324:in `current_session'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/capybara-2.9.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:47:in`page'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/capybara-2.9.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `visit'", "/media/sidharthan/NewVolume/sidharthan_fooddev/foodapp/webapp/food/test/test_helper.rb:115:in`IntegrationTest'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/capybara-2.9.1/lib/capybara.rb:67:in `configure'", "/media/sidharthan/NewVolume/sidharthan_fooddev/foodapp/webapp/food/test/test_helper.rb:102:in`IntegrationTest'", "org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1565:in `instance_exec'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in`make_lambda'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in`simple'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in`call'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in`call'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:782:in`_run_setup_callbacks'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:41:in`before_setup'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:827:in `before_setup'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:105:in`run'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:204:in `capture_exceptions'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:104:in`run'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:255:in `time_it'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:103:in`run'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:348:in `on_signal'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:275:in`with_info_handler'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:102:in `run'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:799:in`run_one_method'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:322:in `run_one_method'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:310:in`run'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:309:in`run'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:348:in `on_signal'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:335:in`with_info_handler'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:308:in `run'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:158:in`__run'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2409:in `map'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:158:in`__run'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:135:in `run'", "/home/sidharthan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest.rb:62:in`autorun'"]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't shown any code or the stacktrace so we could have any clue where the error is coming from - please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.  You're telling Capybara to run its own server, but then telling it to default to the dev server.  Then you're registering a driver inside the configure block? and then also calling `visit` inside the configure block?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi this particualr code working fine in the ruby..but when using jruby the error is occuring..visit google is just simply checking browser is visiting or not.
the code is just a piece to registering a chrome driver..do i need to add the full code here??

Comment: Add the stacktrace so we can see where the error is actually coming from.

Comment: # Running:

requested device config = mobile_generic
Testing with config: mobile_generic
E

Finished in 0.846000s, 1.1820 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
CallCenterTest#test_CallCenter:
ArgumentError: cannot interpret as DNS name: nil
    test/test_helper.rb:113:in `IntegrationTest'
    test/test_helper.rb:101:in `IntegrationTest'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

test_helper.rb:113 line is in the visit method
test_helper.rb:101 line is capybara selenium chrome driver configuration step

Comment: Don’t you have an actual stacktrace? Ie more than just the top level line number

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace you can see it's erring inside https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.9.1/lib/capybara/server.rb#L81 - which is while Capybara is waiting for the application to be tested to start up. 
 This could mean you have set `Capybara.server_host` or `Capybara.server_port` incorrectly.  Without the real code you're running that generates the stacktrace it's impossible to say.

You also probably want to update to the latest 2.x version of Capybara -- 2.9.1 is really old.

Comment: Hi,
i had upgraded the capybara version from 2.9.1 to 2.18.0 but no change in the error..i know the latest version of capybara is 3.3.1 but we are using the ruby version 2.0 for that capybara version need ruby version >=2.3.0..my question is the above code is working in the pure ruby..but application in jruby and ruby inside jruby is 2.0 ..is this will work in jruby-1.7.9?

Comment: @sid Yes it should work, but as I said in my answer you can see from the stacktrace that it's erring while waiting for the application under test server to start.  Further you can see it's while trying to resolve a domain name, so most likley you have probably set `Capybara.server_host` incorrectly (or  possibly  `Capybara.app_host`) or you have a DNS resolution issue on your machine - again it's impossible to say for sure without the relevant code.  The fact it works with MRI is irrelevant because they resolve DNS in completely different manners.